# Retrieve Complete URL from GoogleMaps

Tags: web, browser, chromium, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I'm using CefSharp version 43.0.0 in a large WinForms application, where I pass parameters to Google Maps, i.e., Source and Destination addresses, in order to produce the familiar map and turn-by-turn directions. This works OK. However, I need to capture the much longer, more complete URL that a user would normally get by using Google Maps.

If I take the same parameters, i.e., simple Source from and Destination To address and plug it into any other browser, Google Maps returns a longer, more complete URL containing latitude and longitude address. (Notice the sample shown below).

When I pass the parameters to Google using the Chromium Web Browser (CEF) I get the map, but Not the complete URL.

Could someone suggest how I can get the desired URL when using CEF? Please bear in mind that this is a WinForms App, and not a Web App.

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/2230+Picton+Pkwy,+Akron,+OH+44312/1680+E+Waterloo+Rd,+Akron,+OH+44306/@41.0149182,-81.48249,14z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x88312b00dd84936f:0xb1901f583967068e!2m2!1d-81.467646!2d41.003081!1m5!1m1!1s0x88312bb5f325ca6b:0x48697b37d442dccf!2m2!1d-81.4676985!2d41.0246252
```

Here is what I have tried so far, as shown in the following code. I pass parameters from one form to the form containing the Chromium Browser.

It creates the map with directions, but doesn't return the longer, more complete URL that I would receive if I enter the same parameters manually into another browser like Firefox, Chrome, etc.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
using CefSharp;

namespace myApplication
{
    public partial class myDirectionFinder : Form
    {
        public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;

        public myDirectionFinder()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            if (!CefSharp.Cef.IsInitialized)//Cef can only be initialized once.     Using 'Cef.IsInitialized' guards against an exception.
            {
                CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings);
            }
        }

        private void myDirectionFinder_FormClosing(object sender,     FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            browser = null;
        }

        private void myDirectionFinder_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(txtUrlPasser.Text) { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
            txtFinalAddr.Text = "";
            txtFinalAddr.Text = browser.Address.ToString();
            pnlBrowser.Controls.Add(browser);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What CEF wrapper are you using? What have you tried so far? Version 43 is incredibly old

Comment: I realize the version is old. I pulled it down quite some time ago from the following URL. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp

Comment: @amaitland, please refer to my edited code and comments above, showing what I have tried so far. Please suggest how the CEF browser may be able to retrieve the complete URL that another browser displays when the parameters are entered sent to Google.

Comment: If you were using version 73 you would simply subscribe to http://cefsharp.github.io/api/73.1.x/html/E_CefSharp_WinForms_ChromiumWebBrowser_AddressChanged.htm if the event doesn't exist in version  43 then you'll have to do some digging through the source.

Comment: In future please tag your questions CefSharp,  rare that I check the chromium-embedded tag

Comment: @amaitland. I discovered that version 43 Does have an AddressChanged event. However, the documentation warns that "this event is fired on a CEF UI thread, which by default is not the same as your application UI. To access UI elements you'll need to Invoke/Dispatch onto the UI Thread. The exception to this is when your running with settings.MultiThreadedMessageLoop = false". However, when I attempt to set the above to = false, I receive: "Error: Property or indexer 'CefSharp.CefSettings.MultiThreadedMessageLoop' cannot be assigned to - it is read only" How can I set it false, or Invoke/Dispatch

Comment: @amaitlan. I successfully set MultiThreadedMessageLoop.Equals(false) But, in the browser_AddressChanged event, when I attempt to assign e.Address to the textbox on the browser, I receive the following exception: "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'txtFinalAddr' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." How can I get around this?

Comment: Don't tinker with MultiThreadedMessageLoop unless you know what you are doing.  Search for the error message you are seeing,  it's not CefSharp specific.

Comment: The `MinimalExample` project can be used as a reference, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms/BrowserForm.cs#L76 `InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired` is an extension method, it's also included in the project source.

Comment: @amaitlan The MinimalExample project's InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired example is exactly what I was looking for. This successfully gives me the ability to retrieve the address change that takes place after passing parameters to Google Maps. The methods and examples you provided are much appreciated.